# Set selected option of a SelectElement

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, gwt

I am having a problem with my code to set the selected option of a SelectElement based on condition:

```
@Override
public void setModel(String s) {
    int children = this.getElement().getChildCount();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < children){
        Node child = this.getElement().getChild(i);
        final Element el = child.cast();
        if (Element.is(el)) {
            if(el.getAttribute("attribute_to_check") != null){
                if(el.getAttribute("attribute_to_check").equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                    SelectElement se = this.getElement().cast();
                    se.setSelectedIndex(i);
                }
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Each `<option>` in the `SelectElement` has a unique String attribute named `attribute_to_check` to which the code compares the desired option to be selected.

**The problem is**, if the String that is located at index 0, lets call it `option0`.

- Passing `option0`, the one that gets selected is `option3`,
- if the String passed is `option1` the option that gets selected is
  `option5` and so forth.

What could be wrong with this code that this skipping pattern happens?

Comment: Looks to me the indexes are not aligned. `se` referring to `this` and `child` are both selected with the same index. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, this.getElement() is the actual SelectElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet there are non-element children in the select.

Try incrementing `i` only when `Element.is(el)` or, better, loop over `SelectElement#getOptions()`.